# How to compute variance with missing value in a DataFrame - Python Pandas?

Tags: python, join, pandas, merge, dataframe

To be concrete, say we have a dataframe

df1:

```
name    date    valueA  valueB  color
A   12/1/14     3       10      red
A   12/2/14     1       30      red
B   12/1/14     2       30      green
B   12/3/14     3       20      green
C   12/3/14     4       40      white
```

The range of date is from 12/1/14 to 12/4/14. Each group name is labeled with a "color" that won't change in different days. I want to compute the variance of values within each group of "A", "B", and "C". And **the values for those dates not shown in the dataframe of each group will be assumed 0**.

The expected result with variance is:

```
name varA   varB    color
A   2       20      red
B   2.25    22.5    green
C   4       40      white
```

The following code does not generate expected result.

```
df.groupby("name")['valueA', 'valueB'].var()
```

Comment: What result did you get and what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df.set_index(['date', 'name']).unstack().fillna(0).apply(var)
           name
value  A       1.5000
       B       1.6875
       C       3.0000
dtype: float64
```

To arrange the DataFrame indexed on date with a MultiColumn for name and color:

```
df.set_index(['date', 'name', 'color']).unstack([1, 2]).fillna(0) 
         valueA                valueB              
name          A      B      C       A      B      C
color       red  green  white     red  green  white
date                                               
12/1/14       3      2      0      10     30      0
12/2/14       1      0      0      30      0      0
12/3/14       0      3      4       0     20     40
```

You can then just use the var function on this DataFrame to get the variance of each column:

```
df.set_index(['date', 'name', 'color']).unstack([1, 2]).fillna(0).var()
        name  color
valueA  A     red        2.333333
        B     green      2.333333
        C     white      5.333333
valueB  A     red      233.333333
        B     green    233.333333
        C     white    533.333333
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. Perfect. In addition, is it possible to keep one additional column of color that is associated with each group?